# Image effect, CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate a way of revealing different parts of an image when the user scrolls by it. There are several examples of it on this page: http://apps.npr.org/unfit-for-work/?src=longreads&buffer_share=be155&utm_source=buffer

How does it work? This is what I have extracted so far:

```
h3#image1 {
    background-image: url(story1/1.png);
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

html.backgroundsize .wallpaper { 
    background: center center fixed no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<h3 id="image1" class="wallpaper">Something</h3>
```

But this alone will only give it a background. The background will not scroll and reveal different portions of the image when scrolling past it.

Comment: Have you seen `background-attachment `? There are many divs on this page.

Comment: The images appear to be background images of h3 elements. And those elements don't use background-attachment as far as I can tell.

Comment: this is the parallax isnt it? http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background: center center fixed no-repeat` has the `fixed` attachment instead of the `scroll` attachment. `scroll` will move the background image when you scroll the page, so that the image "will not scroll and reveal different portions of the image when scrolling past it." Using `fixed` under `background:`, or as `background-attachment: fixed;`, will allow the background image to "reveal different portions of the image when scrolling past it."

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the effect is build around the <section> element

**HTML**

```
<section>
      <h3 id="hale-county" class="wallpaper">One In Four</h3>
      ...
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
//background image definition
h3#hale-county {
    background-image: url(../img/hale-county-bus-152.jpg);
}

// wallpaper class is assigned to every h3 element within section
html.backgroundsize .wallpaper {
  ////// THIS PROPERTY IS IMPORTANT FOR THE EFFECT
  background: center center fixed no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only all and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  html.backgroundsize .wallpaper { 
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```